# Meaning of $\Subset$ notation

Tags: notation, complex-dynamics, na.numerical-analysis, computer-science, cv.complex-variables

The symbol $\Subset$ (occurring in places where $\subseteq$ could occur syntactically) comes up frequently in a paper I'm reading.  The paper lives at the intersection of a few areas of math, and I don't even know where to begin looking for the meaning of a symbol whose latex code is "\Subset".  Do you know what this usually denotes?

Edit: some context follows.

All the sets in question are subsets of $\hat{\mathbb{C}} = \mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$.

Example 1. In a situation where $J$ is closed with empty interior, $U$ and $V$ are closed with $U\subsetneq V$, it is written "Note that $J \Subset U$ and, selecting a neighborhood $W \subset U$ of $J$ which is compactly contained in $V$, ..."

Example 2. In a situation where $R$ is a rational mapping, and where it is assumed that $B\subset \hat{\mathbb{C}}$ is such that $R(B)\Subset B$, it is written "Let $\Omega_0 = \hat{\mathbb{C}}\setminus B$.  Define $\Omega_1 = R^{-1}(\Omega_0)$.  By the properties of $B$, we have $\Omega_1\Subset\Omega_0$.  If we let $U_0$ be any finite union of closed balls such that $\Omega_1 \subset U_0 \subset \Omega_0$, ..."

In both cases I have paraphrased to simplify the notation, so I hope I have not introduced errors into it.

Comment: I have seen $A \Subset B$ mean that the (topological) closure of $A$ is contained in $B$, but I'm sure there are plenty of other uses as well.  Could you perhaps provide some context?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In my experience $U \Subset V$ means that the closure of U is a compact subset of V. ${}{}$

Comment: It is much more common, in the sort of papers I read, to see $U\subset\subset V$ for that purpose. However, I find that ugly and have often wanted to use $U\Subset V$ instead. But I have never been sure if that is the recognized use for the symbol.

Comment: $\subset \subset$ is indeed not very pleasing to the eye, but I always understood it to be a form of $C. \subset$ with $C.$ standing for "compact", which would not be so readily recognized if one used $\Subset$.

Comment: And we read $U \Subset V$ as: "$U$ is compactly contained in $V$.

Comment: Taking this answer as a starting point and comparing it with the examples I just added, it seems a related possibility for $U\Subset V$ might be "$U$ has a neighborhood which is compactly contained in $V$".  Has anyone seen it used this way?

Comment: It sounds like this answer is the consensus.  Thanks all!

Comment: So that's the complex analyst's way of saying [way below](http://planetmath.org/waybelow)?

Answer (score 4):

A. I think $U \Subset V$ and $U\subset\subset V$ mean that $U\subset K\subset V$ for some compact $K$, i.e., "$U$ is compactly contained in $V$".

B. In a Hausdorff space, this is equivalent to "$\overline U\subset V$ and $\overline U$ is compact".

C. If $V$ is locally compact Hausdorff, this is equivalent to "$U$ has a neighborhood which is compactly contained in $V$".

Note: open and closed subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ are locally compact. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space

Proofs: B.: If "$\overline U\subset V$ and $\overline U$ is compact", we can take $K:=\overline U$, so assume $U\Subset V$ in a Hausdorff space. Then $K$ is necessarily closed, by http://mathonline.wikidot.com/compact-sets-in-hausdorff-topological-spaces
Always a closed subset of a compact set is compact (proof: add its complement to get an open cover of the latter set); hence so is $\overline U$. As $K$ is closed, $\overline U\subset K\subset V$.

C. $V$ being locally compact means that every point has a compact neighborhood, i.e., $x\in W_x\subset K_x$, where $W_x$ is open and $K_x$ compact.

As $K$ is compact, $K\subset W_{x_1}\cup\cdots\cup W_{x_n}=:W$ for some $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in K$. But $W\subset K_{x_1}\cup\cdots\cup K_{x_n}=:K'$, which is compact in $V$ (hence closed); hence so is $\overline W\subset K'$.
Thus, $U\subset W\subset \overline W\subset V$, QED.

Note: B. is the definition used in the other answer and C. answers Linda's comment to it.

Comment: Isn't this the same as [@anonymous's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/43953) and the comments on it?

Comment: "A." is a different definition, which I have seen often (though perhaps solely in a locally compact Hausdorff?). Their answer is equivalent in a Hausdorff space (see B.), not in general. Linda's comment is equivalent in a locally compact Hausdorff V (see C.), not in general. So I provided an answer that I think is the correct one and proved when the other suggestions are equivalent (which is "usually"). If somebody has sources not assuming Hausdorff, that might provide support to A., but even then B., C. are good to know and answer to Linda's comment.